# Sorting Object by keys numerically with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok, so I am trying to sort out my json data into a table:

```
{
    "0": {
        "1": {
            "airdate": "2011-12-04", 
            "file_size": 368279154, 
            "location": "filepath", 
            "name": "episodename", 
            "quality": "Unknown", 
            "release_name": "", 
            "status": "Downloaded", 
            "subtitles": ""
        }
    }, 
    "1": {
        "1": {
            "airdate": "2011-12-04", 
            "file_size": 368279154, 
            "location": "filepath", 
            "name": "episodename1", 
            "quality": "Unknown", 
            "release_name": "", 
            "status": "Downloaded", 
            "subtitles": ""
        }, 
        "2": {
            "airdate": "2011-12-04", 
            "file_size": 368279154, 
            "location": "filepath", 
            "name": "episodename2", 
            "quality": "Unknown", 
            "release_name": "", 
            "status": "Downloaded", 
            "subtitles": ""
        }, 
        "14": {
            "airdate": "2011-12-04", 
            "file_size": 368279154, 
            "location": "filepath", 
            "name": "episodename14", 
            "quality": "Unknown", 
            "release_name": "", 
            "status": "Downloaded", 
            "subtitles": ""
        }
    }
```

The problem is my angular ng-repeat lists it in order alphabetically ex 1, 14, 2... I can't seem to work with this object to take the key and set it as an ID parameter for the object but I thought that would be the best option. any suggestions would be helpful. I would like to note I cannot alter the server side api.

Comment: Can you post ng-repeat code too?

Comment: html for seasons and episodes: http://pastebin.com/mXyBzUe0

Comment: js for controller: http://pastebin.com/M12q29sQ

Comment: json from server: http://pastebin.com/2QGG5V6G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the order of some collection is important, you should consider using array instead.

if you stick using object, the way is to create an array to keep the object's keys for orderfing purpose

the prototype

```
scope.obj = {"1":{}, "2":{}, "14":{}};
scope.objKeys = ['1', '2', '14'];

<div ng-repeat="key in objKeys">
    {{obj[key]}}
</div>
```